# Google Map Android Api V2 Sample Code not working and display blank page

Tags: android, google-maps

i used google map v2 in my project... 
cod is not working and show blank page in emulator device.
and error in consol :

```
[2014-12-02 17:21:45 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
```

[image: my project picture]

Comment: is your emulator have googlePlayerService installed? or Test in real devic..

Comment: yes...intalled...is working in real device...

Answer (score 1):

You need Google Play Services to be installed on your device to use Google Maps.
Test your app on real device or install Play Services using on emulator ADB.

Comment: i intalled  Google Play Services and google maps in emulator, my project working in real device but not working in emulator :( I also added to the project library Google Play Services

Comment: Does the same error appears in logcat after Play Services addition?